# How do I attach to different classes with the same events at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, late-binding

Given two classes with identical events I'd like to be able to refer to them using one name.  Similar to the following:

```
Public Class myclass1
   Public event1()
End Class

Public Class myclass2
   Public event1()
End Class
```

Here I'd like to be able to determine at run time which class to use:

```
Sub somefunction(select as integer)
   Dim voidclass
   if select = 1 then
      voidclass = myclass1
   else
      voidclass = myclass2
   end if
   AddHandler voidclass.event1, AddressOf eventhappened
End Sub

Sub eventhappened()
   msgbox("Event occured")
End Sub
```

Obviously there may be a better method for this example, but let's assume that class `book1` already exists, and that I'm tasked with creating `book2` and only modifying `somefunction` without modifying `book1` itself.

The example above should result in the error `event1` is not an event of 'Object'`.

It appears that properties and methods are fine with this, but events are not.  How do I handle events in this situation?

Comment: What about casting combined with `GetType()` comparison? Or make a base class which the other classes derive from, where the base class contains the event. Then you can just cast to the base class.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet does not match the question very well.  It has an odd bug, the events in the classes are not declared `Shared` so the code must use a proper object reference.  Not a type name.  Maybe the answer is as simple as:

```
   Private obj1 As myclass1
   Private obj2 As myclass2

   Sub somefunction(select as integer)
       If select = 1 Then
          AddHandler obj1.event1, AddressOf eventhappened
       Else
          AddHandler obj2.event1, AddressOf eventhappened
       End If
   End Sub
```

But presumably the real question is the same scenario, but now the variables declared as:

```
   Private obj1, obj2
```

Untyped and thus `Object`.  Yes, VB.NET does not support that.  As with most quirks in VB.NET there is history behind this. VB never did support explicit late binding of events, only methods and properties.  The scheme in the legacy versions was very quirky.  You had to declare the variable with the `WithEvents` keyword and pick a specific name for the event handler.  In other words:

```
   Dim WithEvents obj1

   Sub obj1_somethinghappened
       '' handles the event1 event for obj1
   End Sub
```

Or to put it another way, all events were late-bound.  This scheme was not carried forward into VB.NET, too many practical problems with it.  `WithEvents` still survives but now requires the `Handles` keyword on the method declaration.  That doesn't do what you want it to do.

The VB.NET designers intentionally did not add late binding support to the `AddHandler` statement.  I am not privy to the exact reason they decided this and can only guess.  There is no technical reason it could not be added, it just requires the compiler to generate reflection code.  One possible explanation is that they considered it too expensive.  Another is that they deemed the runtime exceptions that are raised when there's a method signature mismatch too hard to interpret. I like that last one best, they are awfully ugly.

You'll have to use Reflection to get what you want.  Use obj1.GetType().GetEvent("event1") to get the EventInfo, its Get/AddMethod() to add the event handler.

Fwiw, the C# language does support this in its *dynamic* keyword implementation.  Maybe you can put a bug in their ear by [asking for the feature](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015).  No real idea if this was requested before.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface for the event and implement it in the classes then you can subscribe to this event through the interface reference. See below:

```
Public Interface INotifier
    Event SomethingHappened()
End Interface

Public Class Class1
    Implements INotifier

    Public Event SomethingHappened() Implements INotifier.SomethingHappened
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Implements INotifier

    Public Event SomethingHappened() Implements INotifier.SomethingHappened
End Class

Module Module1

    Dim notifiers As List(Of INotifier) = New List(Of INotifier) From
    {
        New Class1(),
        New Class2()
    }

    Sub Main()
        SubscribeToEventHandler(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SubscribeToEventHandler(ByVal index As Integer)
        Dim notifier As INotifier = notifiers(index)
        AddHandler notifier.SomethingHappened, AddressOf EventHandler
    End Sub

    Private Sub EventHandler()

    End Sub

End Module
```